# Reverse SSH two times from C to B and from A to B to shh from A to C

Tags: ssh, tunnel

My hosts:

- A - windows WSL (can not install ssh in Windows, only in WSL)
- B - ubuntu 16.04, with sudo
- C - redhat 7, without sudo or root

Then access I have:

- I can access B from A
- I can access B from C
- I cannot access C from A or B
- I cannot access A from either A, B, C

I created reverse tunnel from C to B:

```
ssh -f -N -T -R 0.0.0.0:2022:C:22 user@B
```

And reverse tunnel from A to B:

```
ssh -fNT -R 0.0.0.0:2023:A:22 user@B
```

then how to connect directly from A to C?

Answer (score 0):

You need a reverse tunnel from C to B:

```
ssh -f -N -T -R 0.0.0.0:2022:C:22 user@B
```

And a forward tunnel from A to B:

```
ssh -fNT -L 0.0.0.0:2022:127.0.0.1:2022 user@B
```

Then you can connect from A with

```
ssh -p 2022 user@127.0.0.1
```

If firewall rules don't prevent it, you can also use

```
ssh -p 2022 user@B
```